# I want to average by date column Django?

Tags: python, django

I've been working on it for a week, but I couldn't.
This is what he wants to do:
I want to average the "fiyat" column relative to the "ay_yil" column, i.e .:

### { '2020-09-15': 67333.3, '2020-02-15': 29750,0 }

models.py:

```
class Araba(models.Model):    
    marka = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Marka')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Model')
    motor = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Motor')
    yil   = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Yil')
    km    = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Km')
    fiyat = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Fiyat')
    ay_yil= models.DateField(verbose_name='Ay Yıl')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.marka
```

views.py:

```
def veri(request,marka,model,motor):
    veri= Araba.objects.filter(marka=marka,model=model,motor=motor)["ay_yil"]
    veri2=veri.aggregate(ort=Avg('fiyat'))
    print(veri2)  
    return render(request,"veri.html")
```

dataset:
[image]

Comment: Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635951/how-do-i-calculate-the-average-difference-between-two-dates-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Avg

def veri(request, marka, model, motor):
    veri= Araba.objects.filter(marka=marka,model=model,motor=motor).values('ay_yil')
    veri2=veri.annotate(Avg('fiyat'))
    print(veri2)  
    return render(request,"veri.html")
```

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you, I am grateful to you my friend